# Redis - Wrong signature trying to load DB from file

Tags: docker, redis

I'm using Redis image to run the docker container but when start I got this error:

```
redis-server    | 1:M 11 May 2020 09:31:25.479 # Wrong signature trying to load DB from file
redis-server    | 1:M 11 May 2020 09:31:25.479 # Fatal error loading the DB: Invalid argument. Exiting.
```

Btw I'm running it on AWS EC2. Any thought about this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi @Bui Quang Huy, any luck with this error. I am also facing the same issue.

Comment: in my case it just about my DB that redis write to didnt init yet.

Answer (score 4):

Following the suggestion mentioned on this page solved this issue:
https://github.com/redis/redis/issues/6032

1. Find the dump.rdb:

`sudo find / -name *.rdb`

2. Delete the file, for example:

`sudo rm /var/lib/redis/dump.rdb`

Comment: I found the dump.rdb location inside redis config /etc/redis/redis.config, search for "dir" which is a working directory, and it also was /var/lib/redis